# MySQL Server for Web asking for root account password without even setting any password: Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to install the **MySQL Database** on my windows computer. When installing I get the following screens-
[image]

On clicking next I get-
[image]

**Problem- What password do I need to enter on this screen? I tried entering a new password and clicking the check button, but it does not accept any password. I also tried my current account password (used to log in to my laptop) but it also did not work. Please help me get rid of this issue and proceed further.**
I know there are several other answers but they answer about resetting or recovering passwords. In my case, I made a fresh installation for the first time. I don't know what to put in that field.
I tried going back and jumping to the screen-
[image]
I am still not able to login by giving a username and password.

Comment: I believe the default password is non, so just try enter.

Comment: @RohitGupta I cannot proceed without entering a password in the field.

Comment: @Alien I am making a new installation of MySQL from scratch. So, I don't think that it applies.

Comment: It could be **password**, but either way, if it doesnt work the  try resetting it.  I am voting to close the question